# Invalid JSON double quotes error. How can I correct my syntax if i already have double quotes?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a script that reads this one particular section in JSON.
The section in question is:

```
def amifunc2(instance_id):

        client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name = 'us-east-1')

        ec2_response = client.send_command(
            InstanceIds=[
         instance_id
         ],
           DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
            Parameters={
          'commands': [
               '#!/bin/bash',
---
               'admin_users=( user.number.1 user.number.2 user.number.3 user.number.4 )',
               'for i in ${admin_users[@]}; do aws ssm send-command --document-name "arn:aws:ssm:doc-name" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=$instance_id" --parameters "{"\""username"\"":["\""$i"\""]}" --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region us-east-1 --query "Command.CommandId"; sleep 5; done',
```

I run this command and get:

```
Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {username:[user.number.1]}
Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {username:[user.number.2]}
Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {username:[user.number.3]}
Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {username:[user.number.4]}
```

the parameters section of the first section is what is in question. I have tried all double quote combinations yet the AWS console reports it as invalid JSON format. What is the issue with my syntax?

Comment: Look again. The code utilizes the loop ```for i in``` then takes in the list of admin users and puts in into the ```--parameters "{"\""username"\"":["\""$i"\""]}"``` section.

Comment: Those quotes are being interpreted by the shell. wrap the arg in single quotes.

Comment: Woudn't this be sufficient? `'"{\"username\":[\"$i\"]}"'`

Comment: Yes, that should work and also `--parameters "{\"username\":[\"$i\"]}"` as a bit less complicated version. something related to SSM itself might be the cause

Comment: Those do not work for some reason, what should i check on ssm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using a combination of single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) which allows the values to be echoed as intended, so the parameters would be wrapped in `\'"{"username":["\'$i\'"]}"\'`.

Below is a working snippet.

```
def amifunc2(instance_id):

        client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name = 'us-east-1')

        ec2_response = client.send_command(
            InstanceIds=[
         instance_id
         ],
           DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
            Parameters={
          'commands': [
               '#!/bin/bash',
---
               'admin_users=( user.number.1 user.number.2 user.number.3 user.number.4 )',
               'for i in ${admin_users[@]}; do aws ssm send-command --document-name "arn:aws:ssm:doc-name" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=$instance_id" --parameters \'"{"username":["\'$i\'"]}"\' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region us-east-1 --query "Command.CommandId"; sleep 5; done',
```